Cell will not change
I have a cell that will not show anything else but the number "0". I have erased it, added a formula, changed font, size, color and nothing will show up but a "0". DOes anyone know how to change that?
I have erased it, added a formula, changed font, size, color and nothing will show up but a "0".

Welcome to StackOverFlow! Please take this opportunity to take the tour and learn how to ask, format the code, create a minimal reproducible example, etc.

By any chance, do you have any ARRAYFORMULA/LAMBDA/QUERY/FILTER/etc. formulas on the previous rows?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
